# access button of another component which is on same level

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular2-template, angular-ui

I am using websocket in component 1 when i recieve some value through websocket i want to change the status of a button to disconnect which is in component 2.I am using  event emitter for that but it is not working

Comment: let me explain the scenario , i m making a application when i plug a usb i receive a value in my websocket that is in different component and user can connect to that hardware and when hw is connected and user plugged out the usb then connected button should change to connect

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using Subject/Behavior Subject.

Service:

```
public subject: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
public subject$ = subject.asObservable();
```

Component 1:

```
service.subject.next('change');
```

Component 2:

```
service.subject$.subscribe((value)=>{
  if(value){

  }
});
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not going on subscribe statement

Comment: it is not working,these two components are in different modules

Answer (score 0):

Use **Subject** like this,

In service.ts:

```
subject = new Subject<any>();
```

In component1.ts:

```
commonService.subject.next('change');
```

and in `component2.ts` subscribe change event

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.commonService.subject.subscribe(res => {
            this.some_var = res;
    });
}
```